# I want to make a call using Nougat Device i have also given permission but still cannot open dial pad

Tags: android

Using below intent I am trying to make a call.But in Nougat device Dial pad is not opening

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+phone));
startActivity(intent);`
```

Below is the code for run time permission

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23){
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(InsertManuallyActivity.this,
                Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(InsertManuallyActivity.this,
                    Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE)) {
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(InsertManuallyActivity.this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE},PERMISSIONS_REQUEST);
            }
        }else{
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(InsertManuallyActivity.this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE},
                    PERMISSIONS_REQUEST);
        }
    }else {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+phone));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

This is my onRequestPermissionResult

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CALL: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                callPhone("911");
            } else {

                Snackbar.make(llCall, "Please enable permission from setting", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .setActionTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_red_dark)).show();
            }

            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: have you handled permissions at runtime?

Comment: Yes i have add runtime permission also but still i am facing issue

Comment: can you post the code that is part of runtime permission handling?

Comment: Please check now i have added permission code what i'm doing wrong

Comment: what about the `onRequestPermissionsResult`? have you implemented that?

Comment: you sure your device is Nougat?

Comment: you should use libs: https://github.com/hotchemi/PermissionsDispatcher

Comment: @NguyễnTrungHiếu Yes i have a Nougat device (Moto G5 Plus)

Comment: @SunilShreepal is it your problem solved?

Comment: @UmarulFarukh I have remove all permission's and used your given code and i solved my problem. Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+phone));
startActivity(intent);`

**If you use this code u can get the value to dial pad. So we dont use permission for call....**